# SQL Search query: search for values that don't meet a specific format requirement in a column

Tags: sql

I want to search for rows that don't have a specific format in a particular column. The column values should contain the value from another column in it.
for eg.

| id | location | time | image_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID001 | PARIS | Evening | imageID001Paris00115.jpg |
| ID002 | London | Morning | imageID002London00130.jpg |
| ID003 | New York | Afternoon | newyorkimage1.jpg |

This is the search format that I am trying to achieve.

```
SELECT * from <table> where image_col NOT LIKE 'image<{id}><{location}><{somefilenumber}>.jpg'
```

The output of the above query for the table will be like this:

| id | location | time | image_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID003 | New York | Afternoon | newyorkimage1.jpg |

Comment: Hi, you can just concatenate the columns together to get the comparison value for the LIKE.  I guess it may depend on exactly what your RDBMS is, to determine exactly what will be syntactically correct or not.  For example, for SQL Server I could do SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE image_col NOT LIKE ('image' + id + location + '[0123456789]%.jpg')

Comment: Tag the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table

| id | location | time | image_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID001 | PARIS | Evening | imageID001Paris00115.jpg |
| ID002 | London | Morning | imageID002London00130.jpg |
| ID003 | New York | Afternoon | newyorkimage1.jpg |

Query

```
SELECT id, location, time, image_col
FROM my_table
WHERE image_col NOT LIKE CONCAT('image', id, location, '%.jpg');
```

Output

| id | location | time | image_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID003 | New York | Afternoon | newyorkimage1.jpg |